# PDC giving empty DNS responses to a Mac in the network

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, mac-osx, ipv6

I have a small network with two computers (Windows XP), a Mac (OS X 10.6), a printer (Konica Minolta C250) and a server (Windows Server 2008 Standard SP2 x64).

Lately, after configuring a shared folder for scanning on the Mac, the Mac started to get really slow on startup, shutdown and sometimes in between too. In order for it to start/shutdown I had to take the network cable and plug it back in.

I ran Wireshark on the server to monitor the Mac requests and noticed a DNS request for the server's FQN by the Mac.

This was the output (IPv6 is deactivated in the Mac and in the Server):

> "22857    1086.302117000  192.168.1.41    192.168.1.2 DNS 84  Standard query 0x3530  AAAA servidor.soengenho.local
>
> 22858 1086.302243000  192.168.1.2 192.168.1.41    DNS 131 Standard query response 0x3530"

The normal output to another computer is, for example (coming from a Windows XP machine):

> "20138    948.242215000   192.168.1.40    192.168.1.2 DNS 84  Standard query 0xe413  A SERVIDOR.soengenho.local
>
> 20138  948.242215000   192.168.1.40    192.168.1.2 DNS 84  Standard query 0xe413  A SERVIDOR.soengenho.local"

If I do a *nslookup*, it answers correctly pointing at the server IP:

> ">servidor
>
> Server: servidor.soengenho.local
>
> Address: 192.168.1.2
>
> Name: servidor.soengenho.local
>
> Address: 192.168.1.2"

May this be the true problem causing the Mac startup/shutdown slowness? Or am I just wasting time with something unrelated?

Comment: In years past, Macs had problems with queries to DNS namespaces using .local because they wanted to use .local for the bonjour service. It's been a while since I had to fight that monster. EDIT: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious difference between the first and the second query is that the first one is asking for an `AAAA` record - the IPv6 address for the name `servidor.soengenho.local`. It likely is getting NXDOMAIN in return (although the response code is not part of the sniplet you've provided).

> May this be the true problem causing the Mac startup/shutdown slowness?

My experience with Mac/AD integration is limited, but in the Windows world, DNS problems are a sure recipe for slow startup and logon times or logon errors at the clients. [This Apple KB article (TS4041)](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4041) indicates that you might be hitting a known problem, so you should re-enable IPv6 on both, your server and your Macs and add AAAA and the accompanying PTR records for `servidor.soengenho.local` to your AD DNS server's zones.

Comment: Thank you very much, activating IPv6 on both ends and creating the reverse lookup IPv6 zone, I was able to suppress the multiple DNS queries and get a correct answer pointing to the server.

The startup and shutdown delays are gone now :)

Comment: @Andrédias glad to hear that.